# i'm using select box using ajax,jsp and servlet .. i want to show select box with checkbox in 2nd dependent dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

```
    // index.jsp 

> this is index.jsp file which contains 2 dropdown after selection of country i want to show states with checkbox having problem in this code ...... select with checkbox in state dropdown not showing states may be there is problem with jquery

        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


             <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                    });
                    $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
                        var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
                        var message = "";
                        selected.each(function () {
                            message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
                        });
                        alert(message);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#country').change(function(event) {  
                var $country=$("select#country").val();
                   $.get('ActionServlet',{countryname:$country},function(responseJson) {   
                    var $select = $('#lstFruits');   

                       $select.find('option').remove();                          
                       $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {               
                           $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);      
                            });
                    });
                });
            });          
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <h4>AJAX calls to Servlet using JQuery and JSON</h4>
        Select Country:
        <select id="country">
        <option>Select Country</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        </select>





            <select  multiple="multiple"  id="lstFruits">
                <option >Select SubCategory</option>



            </select>

          <input type="button" id="btnSelected" value="Get Selected" />

        </body>
        </html>
```

//Action servlet

> action servlet which takes request from index.jsp and response in the form of json  dynamic dependent select box in state section checkbox is not working can anybody tell me what's problem in it

```
package com;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class ActionServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/ActionServlet")
public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ActionServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


          String country=request.getParameter("countryname");


          System.out.println(country);


          Map<String, String> ind = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();


             ind.put("1", "New delhi");


             ind.put("2", "Tamil Nadu");


             ind.put("3", "Kerala");


             ind.put("4", "Andhra Pradesh");



             Map<String, String> us = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();



             us.put("1", "Washington");


             us.put("2", "California");


             us.put("3", "Florida");




             us.put("4", "New York");




             String json = null ;


             if(country.equals("India")){


              json= new Gson().toJson(ind);   
             }

             else if(country.equals("US")){


              json=new Gson().toJson(us);  


             }


             response.setContentType("application/json");



             response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");



             response.getWriter().write(json);  





         }



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */





    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: did you get some error?

Comment: no there is not error everything working fine but in checkbox values are  not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop to append all new options in place of:

```
 $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {               
      $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);      
 });
```

Try with this:

```
$.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
    $select.append($('<option>', {
         value: key,
         text: value
}));
```

Comment: not working ..............  $('#country')   $('#lstFruits')  could you check two funtions

Comment: @Abhishek could you check that receives data from the controller? and in the right format?

Comment: yeah i checked it's fine ............ but calling two functions may  me conflict the code